# how to wait until margin size changes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am doing automation testing using visual studio.While selecting list from **dropdown**,only margin size changes.

[image]

I also tried using cssselector to wait but it's not works because cssselector is constant it not changes only the style attribute changes its size.How can wait for margin size to change. Only this part is keep on changing i have to wait until it changes its style.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more. what is your use case and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @NarendraR only the style is keep on changing according to the dropdown type.I have to wait for the style attribute.Is it possible to wait only using style?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a [*custom Expected Condition*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21339339/771848) to track the element location change.

Something along these lines:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

IWebElement personAddress = d.FindElement(By.Id("window_personaddress_edit"));
string personAddressLocation = personAddress.Location;

wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.Id("window_personaddress_edit"));
    string newLocation = element.Location;
    if (newLocation.X != personAddressLocation.X || newLocation.Y != personAddressLocation.Y)
    {
        return element;
    }

    return null;
});
```

where `d` is your webdriver instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a WAG: To change margin style, element has to be redrawn. So you can wait until reference becomes stale, then wait some more until element appears again.

in Python: ExpectedConditions.staleness_of(element)